# How to use different network interface for signaling & media in WebRTC app?

Tags: network-programming, webrtc

I would like to use different network interfaces for signaling and media (WebRTC programming).
Suppose I have more that one network interface like one LAN & Other is WiFi or Usb Modem etc.
1. signaling should be happened via LAN.
2. Media (Video/audio) should use the network interface like Wi-Fi or Usb modem.

Could you please suggest how to achieve above scenario in WebRTC application?

Comment: Why do you need different interfaces? As far as I know, you cannot choose the interface that is used.

Comment: Actually if I have more than one interface and The default network should be used by all other application. My WebRTC application should use  the default network  for signaling and other network interface for media. It will help if only low bandwidth interfaces are available and this is better way to have uninterrupted media communication with WebRTC app. so please suggest.

Comment: Are you using this via javascript in a browser?  AFAIK, you can't get a list of network interfaces from javascript.  You could modify the SDP and ICE candidates if you knew which IP addresses to swap out.

Comment: I have implemented some APIs that return the IP addresses to browser via JS. But now question is this how to push these IP addresses to WebRTC API for signaling and media? I am new to WebRTC. So please guide me, how to modify SDP & ICE as you have suggested above.